# I am confused about my output that gives the closest average of sum of numbers entered by the user.(rounds the decimal to a whole number)

Tags: c, loops, decimal

Complete the following program to find the closest number to average in the array.
    For example, the array {2, 4, 6, 3, 9, 10} has average of 5.666667 and closest number to average
    in the array is 6. Note that closest number can be larger than or smaller than the average.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    double num[6],average, sum=0, closest;
    printf("Enter 6 doubles\n"); //2,4,6,9,3,10

    for (i=0; i<6; i++)
        scanf("%lf",&num[i]);

    //professor's code
    for (i=0; i<6; i++)
        sum += num[i]; //sum=34

    average=sum/6; //5.6666667
    closest = num[0]; //why are we even using this??? //initialize?

    for (i=0; i<6; i++)
        if(fabs(num[i]-average) < fabs(closest-average)) //|6-5.7|<|0-5.7|-> 0.7<5.7->true 
            closest = num[i]; // why is it giving 6?? 
   //where is it being rounded to the closest number??

    //professor's code ends     


    printf("Closest is %lf\n", closest);
    return(0);

}

//Output:
//Closest is 6
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: the reason you  are using `closest=num[0]` is because you are using `closest` once in the if statement BEFORE `closest = num[i]` it's the if absolute value of the difference between the current number and the average `fabs(num[i] - average` is less than the absolute value of difference between the current known closest value and average `fabs(closest - average)` replace the closest value by the current number `closest = num[i]`

Comment: OP's questions are in the comments ....

Answer (score 2):

Your title and code comments suggest that you think the program (always) returns the whole number closest to the average of its inputs.  It does not.  It returns the *input* that is closest to the average of all the inputs.  That will of course be a whole number if all the inputs are whole numbers, but you're inputting them as floating-point numbers, so they need not be whole numbers.  The output therefore needn't be one, either.

For example, if these inputs are presented to your program:

> 1 2 2 2 2 1.8

, it will accept them and output

> Closest is 1.800000

.  Additionally, the output is not certain to be particularly close to the average.  For example, try these inputs:

> 1 1 1 1 1 1000000

.  You should get

> Closest is 1.000000

.  That's a whole number, but it misses the average by about 166666.

With respect to the questions embedded in the code:

> ```
>     closest = num[0]; //why are we even using this??? //initialize?
> ```

The loop immediately following that in the code looks for inputs that are closer to the average than `closest` is.  That's meaningless if `closest` has not been assigned a value, and it potentially leads to the wrong result if `closest` does not contain a value equal to one of the inputs.  Of course, with `closest` starting with the same value as `num[0]`, the output would be the same if the loop started testing at index 1 instead of index 0.

> ```
>    //where is it being rounded to the closest number??
> ```

It is not rounded.  At that point, `closest` already contains a value equal to one of the inputs.  It does not need to be rounded, and in fact rounding would in many cases yield a result that was not among the inputs.